# Comment dire « to pepper spray »?

Tags: traduction, choix-de-mot

Comme l’indique le titre, j’ai du mal à trouver une traduction fidèle pour cette locution. J’ai pensé aux traductions suivantes mais aucune ne me plaît.

- Se servir d’une bombe lacrymogène
- Asperger quelqu’un de gaz à poivre

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En français on ne parle que de gaz lacrymogène en ignorant sa composition<sup>1</sup>. L'expression habituelle est « asperger de gaz lacrymogène ». Parfois, de façon familière, lacrymogène est abrégé en « lacrymo ».

> Il asperge de gaz lacrymogène deux personnes suite à une querelle de voisinage ([La Dépêche d'Évreux](https://actu.fr/normandie/evreux_27229/evreux-il-asperge-de-gaz-lacrymogene-deux-personnes-suite-a-une-querelle-de-voisinage_41594326.html))

> Pompier aspergé de gaz lacrymogène par un gendarme ([Franceinfo](https://www.francetvinfo.fr/societe/mobilisation-des-pompiers/pompier-asperge-de-gaz-lacrymogene-par-un-policier-le-journaliste-a-l-origine-du-cliche-raconte-la-scene_3661601.html))

> Il repère des rôdeurs et se voit aspergé de gaz lacrymogène ([La voix du nord](https://www.lavoixdunord.fr/588385/article/2019-05-24/il-repere-des-rodeurs-et-se-voit-asperge-de-gaz-lacrymogene))

On peut trouver d'autres tournures :

> la victime a été atteinte par le jet de la lacrymo ([Le télégramme](https://www.letelegramme.fr/morbihan/auray/gaze-a-la-lacrymo-sur-le-parking-de-discotheque-de-ploemel-le-videur-devant-le-tribunal-31-08-2021-12816526.php))

> Ils nous balançaient des bombes lacrymo, ça éclate rouge et ça t'en file plein les yeux et la bouche. (*Les liens du sang*, Michel et Bruno Papet)

> Les forces de l'ordre ont dû faire usage de gaz lacrymogène afin de repousser l'intrusion. ([La Dépêche du midi](https://www.ladepeche.fr/2021/10/16/manif-antipass-a-toulouse-quelques-centaines-de-personnes-et-des-jets-de-lacrymo-9857422.php))

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Le gaz lacrymogène contient du [capsicum](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capsicum.) (piment)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

Dans un registre relâché, un verbe souvent employé est ***gazer<sup>1</sup>*** (*se faire gazer* pour la personne qui reçoit le gaz lacrymogène) :

> "On les a gazés dans les formes réglementaires", a-t-il soutenu, indiquant avoir procédé aux sommations d'usage. [Europe 1](https://www.europe1.fr/societe/brest-des-gilets-jaunes-bloquent-un-pont-avant-detre-deloges-par-la-police-3834968)

> "On s'est fait gazer toute la matinée" : les revendications des "gilets jaunes" éclipsées par les violences, place d'Italie à Paris ([France Info](https://www.francetvinfo.fr/economie/transports/gilets-jaunes/on-s-est-fait-gazer-toute-la-matinee-les-revendications-des-gilets-jaunes-eclipsees-par-les-violences-place-d-italie-a-paris_3706895.html))

<sup>1</sup>  <sub>Reprise atténuée du sens militaire: [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/gazer/1) *Intoxiquer (quelqu'un) avec des gaz de combat.*</sub>